# How can I make AWS work as IdP for OIDC or SAML provider?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, openid-connect, saml

I am planning to use `IAM` and `cognito` identity pool as OIDC or SAML provider.
My goal is to use AWS as the provider without any third party integration.

I looked at IAM `Identity Provider` and have read through a doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_create_oidc.html but it seems I need to provide `Metadata document` for SAML or `Provider URL and audience` for OIDC from third party providers.

Is there a way to use AWS as the provider? I don't want to use any other providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is your high level goal:

- Modern and standard security for UIs and APIs via OAuth 2.0 and Open ID Connect

Then a Cognito user pool is probably what you are looking for. This will provide standards based endpoints, so that you can code your UIs and APIs in the preferred way.

If I remember rightly, an Identity Pool is a non standard solution for getting AWS specific tokens used to access user specific AWS resources. You should be able to use that when required by getting the User Pool to talk to the Identity Pool.

**NOTES**

From an application viewpoint the first step is usually always to locate the Open ID Connect metadata endpoint - a lot of security libraries in UIs and APIs will use that.

- [My Metadata Endpoint](https://cognito-idp.eu-west-2.amazonaws.com/eu-west-2_qqJgVeuTn/.well-known/openid-configuration)
- [Cognito OpenID Connect Setup](https://authguidance.com/2018/12/02/cognito-authorization-server-setup/)
- [Cognito Federated Logins](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/)

Cognito is not the most mature of systems and has some annoyances and limitations. So it is worth keeping your solution based on OAuth 2.0 and Open ID Connect so that you have the best longer term options - and can switch providers if ever needed ...

Comment: Can cognito work as OpenId provider? I can't find issuer url and audience in cognito. These values will be used by clients

Comment: The issuer URL is my metadata link above. Audience is missing from access tokens - one of the annoyances - but not a fatal one. My [Quick Start Page](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/) has some Open ID Connect apps you can run - all of which use my AWS Cognito account.