# Windows Service integration with Cognito

Tags: c#, authentication, authorization, windows-services, amazon-cognito

I try to understand what is the best way for integration between Windows Service and AWS Cognito.

I have windows application is based on Windows Service (C#).This app with a minimal UI is installed by customer and after installation it runs as a background process (Windows service). So, user interacts with the app on installation process only.

This app uses AWS resources: write to one S3 bucket and read from another S3 bucket.

So, my questions:

How can I integrate my service with AWS Cognito with Authentication and Authorization functionality? Where should the app save the sensitive data like access token or authorization token? Also, maybe somebody can advise me an another solution, it doesn't have to be a solution with Cognito.

Most of the articles that I have seen about my issue, they are written about mobile/web applications.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your question is an anti-pattern: long lived credentials.  Most of the modern frameworks, including AWS's, want to you semi-continuously trade in proof of your identity in exchange for a short lived token.  That is why I think you are going to have trouble getting a lot of support from blogs/AWS articles on the topic.  Cognito is a decent choice because of the relative ease of the parts that handle the actual handoff to AWS services (you can do some of this 'yourself' with IAMs support of IdPs, but the policies and code - assumeRole's - is a bit trickier to get working smoothly).  Here is a [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_providers_oidc.html) talking about why the long-term credential is a bad idea and is equally true on desktops as on mobile applications:

> When you write such an app, you'll make requests to AWS services that must be signed with an AWS access key. However, we **strongly** recommend that you do **not** embed or distribute long-term AWS credentials with apps that a user downloads to a device, even in an encrypted store. Instead, build your app so that it requests temporary AWS security credentials dynamically when needed using *web identity federation*. The supplied temporary credentials map to an AWS role that has only the permissions needed to perform the tasks required by the mobile app.

If you use cognito, you will be cycling out the temporary credentials.  You can just store them in memory and fetch new ones when they expire or your client's service restarts.  The idea is that they aren't that valuable because they will be expired in a short time.  Also, realize you get to set how long the credentials can last.  Currently, AWS supports between [60 minutes and 10 years](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-user-pools-using-the-refresh-token.html).  If you only require the authentication on boot, for example, that may lower the barrier you have for users and then you bypass the whole 'need to save the credentials' item as you can just keep it in memory.  However, periodic revalidation is still preferable.  I think cognito used to default to 30 days.

If you really, really want to do long term credentials, you don't need cognito at all - just some way of getting a user their credentials to use, which could be generated by you or depending on how big your user base is.  Then you need some way of storing them.  Either you get the user to supply some passphrase on startup and then encrypt/decrypt symmetrically in memory, or you sacrifice even more security by storing them somewhere permanently (perhaps a little bit by obscurity like a 'encrypted' file with a static non-user passphrase).  However, I would **highly** suggest you not take this route at all - it is all a compromise away from temporary credentials which is a best practice for this type of thing.

This related SO may also be helpful with some additional [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66898409/how-can-i-make-aws-work-as-idp-for-oidc-or-saml-provider).

Comment: I don't want to use long term credentials, BUT I can't ask user to sign-in (revalidation) after each time a token is expired or client's service restarts. I'm looking for a way to combine these two requirements. I know that in Cognito I can use a refresh token and change an access token every X minutes, but it seems like "long term credentials".